# ASP.NET MVC application with YAF - SSO integration issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, yaf

I've developed ASP.NET MVC application. I want to integrate it with YAF (YetAnotherForum.NET) and provide SSO (Single Sign-On) for it.

What I've done is I've created virtual directory for YAF in IIS and simply added a link to YAF from my app. My app uses custom membership provider (derived from .net MembershipProvider class). I've configured YAF to use the same provider. Now it's obvious, when I've logged in to my app, and next click on the link to YAF, I have to log in again.

What is the best practice to provide SSO for such situation ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It can solve your problem,
http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postsm49557_User-Login.aspx#post49557

Comment: wayback for dead link:  https://web.archive.org/web/20130126163032/http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postsm49557_User-Login.aspx